# configure linux box to have a static ip

Tags: linux, networking, dns, debian, debian-based

I need to make a machine on my home network use a static ip address. It's a linux box.

My question is can I make just my linux box use a static ip address where the rest of my network (which is comprised of all windows machines linked up to a router) uses dynampic ip's?

It not so much the info on configuring the linux box to use a static ip it's just i'm confused - does my whole network have to use a static ip if I want to use a static ip on one box?

Many thanks

Comment: Type of internet connection?
Structure of your home network?
Current settings of the box?

Comment: This is off-topic on SO.  It belongs on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your router is probably running a dhcp server, so you should set your linux box to an ip which is not covered by the dhcp range of your router.

See `man interfaces` for information about how to set the static ip for your debian.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make your PC use a static ip while the rest of the network remains on DHCP

I'm Running Ubuntu Lucid (10.04)

2 options

1. System->Preferences->NetworkConnection then editing the eth0 setting ipv4 to manual and set appropriate settings.
2. manually edit the /etc/network/interfaces file, I added the following

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.7

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 192.168.0.0

broadcast 192.168.0.255

gateway 192.168.0.1

Comment: ah ok...looks promising. I'm running debian but no prob to edit the interfaces file. Problem is i'm not sure which ip address I should pick. I think it's got to be out of the range that my router can assign and I don't know what that is

Comment: well for my network i've configure my router to use 192.168.0.100 - .199 for dhcp. Now all static address are 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.99, 192.168.0.1 is the router address. There is no setting in my router to specify which ip's are static. However... it can assign a static ip to a certain MAC. But what if you change the network card in your pc, it won't get that static ip cause the MAC is different. This is why I get the OS to use the static ip

Comment: Aha - gave me enough to go on there. My router also allows me to assign a static ip based on MAC address. but i've just managed to find out that my router has a range of 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254 so i can go in to interfaces file and create an entry like the one you posted above. Only problem now is i'm not sure what ip address i should use - I can;t do 192.168.1.xxx as that whole range (from 1 to 255 is taken by the router)so can i use something like 192.168.2.xxx?

Comment: well you could tell your router not to use that whole range, that way your whole network will be on 192.168.1.xxx .

Answer (score 0):

Most of the routers have option to assign static ip to a mac addres. Let you Linux box on dhcp. Log on to router setting page. There should be a setting page to assign static ip to a given MAC address. This is available on Linksys router. If your doesn't support than see if you can flash your router with dd-wrt/open-wrt/tomato. these firmware definatly support this feature.

If you still want to configure you **Linux** client and not the router than i suggest you pick the highest fourth quad number. Router will not use that ip unless you have so many box on the network.